# Numpy: Calculate the mean for each subset of rows in efficient way

Tags: python, numpy

Given there is a `H` by `W`, 2d array `x` and a 1d array `y` of length `H` which specifies each row of `x` is assigned to class `y_i`. For example,

```py
x: [[1, 2, ...],
    [3, 4, ...],
    ...         ]

y: [1, 3, 0, 2, ...]
```

This means that the first row of x is in class `1` and second row is in class `3` and so on.

Then, I need to calculate the mean of rows for each class. I have came up with one way of doing so by looping over the class. Here is the example input and output.

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]])
y = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1])

row_means = np.ndarray([k, W]) # k is the max value in y so number of classes
for i in y:
    row_means[i] = x[y == i].mean(axis=0)

row_means: array([[2. , 3. , 4. ],
                  [2.5, 3.5, 4.5]])
```

Yet, I want to calculate it without using any loop. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Your example code does not make much sense. you are redefining `row_means` each iteration, and while I think I've understood what you mean by `X[y==I]` thanks to your explanation, I don't think it works. Could you post an actual working example with a sample input and expected result?

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected and add sample input and output.

Comment: Do you specifically need a `numpy` only solution? This problem would likely be simpler using `pandas`

Comment: It won't remove the loop, but as a quick tip use `for i in set(y):`. It will avoid to repeat the same calculations when the elements in `y` are equals

Comment: Yes, I can not use pandas for this.

Comment: I think one loop is unavoidable here, because each value in `y` may be assigned to a different _number_ of rows in `x`. And since numpy arrays don't support irregular shapes, all such rows cannot be fetched as a single array at the same time, making the loop to iterate over unique `y` values necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one line solution would be using a list comprehension instead of a loop, using `set(y)` to avoid to repeat the calculations for the same values in `y`:

```
row_means = np.array([x[y==i].mean(axis=0) for i in set(y)])
```

which with your `x` and `y` returns:

```
array([[2. , 3. , 4. ],
       [2.5, 3.5, 4.5]])
```

If your concern is performance, this solution is ~1.5 times more efficient than the solution with the loop, even using `for i in set(y)` instead of `for i in y`. On my machine at least.